# TypeScript and Node

Tags: node.js, typescript

Are there any limitations using TypeScript in a Node project compared to using Javascript at the server side for a web application?

Are all existing Node modules out there totally reusable without modification?

(PS: I am ok to use Visual Studio as the IDE.)

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any limitations using TypeScript in a Node project compared to using Javascript

No. You just have the overhead of setting up TypeScript, for the sake of its advantages : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

> Are all existing Node modules out there totally reusable without modification?

Yes. Just set `allowJs:true` in your tsconfig and you don't even need a declaration file.

Comment: Thanks. Can an app developed in VS be deployed on a non-Windows server?

Comment: Yes. it compiles to JavaScript which runs everywhere.